# Redux dispatch boolean returns non-serializable error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to use Redux to set a boolean in the state to show/hide an element.

Whenever I dispatch a boolean the following error shows:
*A non-serializable value was detected in the state*, which is weird as a boolean is perfectly serializable?

Todo.js

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

export default function Planner() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function createHandleClickOpen() {
    dispatch(createDialogOpen(true));
  }
```

createHandleClickOpen is bound on a button's onClick() method.

Plannerstore.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const plannerSlice = createSlice({
  name: "planner",
  initialState: {
    createDialogOpen: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    createDialogOpen: (state) => (value) => {
      state.createDialogOpen = value;
    },
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { createDialogOpen } = plannerSlice.actions;

export default plannerSlice.reducer;
```

Store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import plannerSlice from "../../feature/planner/plannerStore";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    planner: plannerSlice,
  },
});
```

Comment: `dispatch(createDialogOpen(true));` first calls `createDialogOpen(true)` and then passes the returned value to `dispatch()`.  The function `createDialogOpen()` does not return anything, so that's effectively `dispatch(undefined)`.

Comment: @Pointy No, that's not how dispatch works, it doesn't expect a returning value.

Comment: I believe the action created by Redux Toolkit with `export const { createDialogOpen } = plannerSlice.actions;` returns an `ActionCreatorWithPayload<boolean>` in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in your reducer.

You should use the action payload to retrieve the value you dispatch:

```js
export const plannerSlice = createSlice({
  name: "planner",
  initialState: {
    createDialogOpen: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    createDialogOpen: (state, action) => {
      state.createDialogOpen = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The specific issue here is that the reducer is written incorrectly.

You have:

```
createDialogOpen: (state) => (value) => {
      state.createDialogOpen = value;
    },
```

That means that it's "a function that takes `state` as an argument, and returns a function that takes `value` as an argument".

The result of a reducer *is* what it returns (or in the case of RTK + Immer, what you "mutate" in `state`).  So, the problem here is that you are *returning a function*, and functions are not serializable.

The other issue is that we don't use `value` to describe any of the arguments to a reducer.  The arguments are `(state, action)`, and with `createSlice`, what normally matters is the `action.payload` field.

As noted in the other comment, the correct syntax would be:

```
    createDialogOpen: (state, action) => {
      state.createDialogOpen = action.payload;
    },
```